# Will these small arborvitaes grow back?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-recommendations, deer

[image]I planted these small arborvitaes 2 years ago and the deer got right to them. I’ve recently started protecting them with a fence, but the deer chewed them up during the winter time. I’m wondering if these will grow back or if it’s too late for that. Thanks!